# haskell quick sort, why the first let uses <= instead of <?

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) =
    let smallerOrEqual = [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
        larger = [a | a <- xs, a > x]
    in quicksort smallerOrEqual ++ [x] ++ larger

main = do
    let a = [ 5, 1, 9, 4, 6, 7, 3]
    print  $ quicksort a
```

in Haskell quick sort, why the first `let` uses `<=` instead of `<`? I think `<=` will duplicate that `x` many times. Why not?

Comment: Because it is trying to be stable.

Comment: If you use `<` instead of `<=`, the resulting list will be an ascending version of the original list *but with all duplicates removed*. However, removing dupes is not what sorting is about.

Comment: @Jubobs but,, is it keep including the "x"? I don't get that part. How to get rid of one each time.

Comment: @BufBills Not sure what you mean... Sorting, strictly speaking, is not about dropping dupes; the resulting list should just be a sorted version of the list you pass to `quicksort`; the two lists should have the same length. By the way, you're missing a function call; it should be `quicksort smallerOrEqual ++ [x] ++ quicksort larger`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think <= will duplicate that x many times

No, it will not. Let us understand what exactly is happening here. You are basically partitioning your list into three parts.

1. List of numbers smaller than or equal to the pivot element (excluding the first element, since that is the pivot element)
2. The pivot element itself (the first element in the list)
3. List of numbers greater than the pivot element

So, in your case, the partitioned list becomes like this

```
[1, 4, 3] ++ [5] ++ [9, 6, 7]
```

Consider a case like this, `quicksort [5, 1, 5, 9, 8, 5, 3, 6, 4]`. Then, your program will partition it into something like this

```
smallerOrEqual ++ [x] ++ larger
```

Since `smallerOrEqual` and `larger` work with `xs`, which doesn't have the `x`, there is no duplication as such. Now, the partitioned list, after the filtering, becomes

```
[1, 5, 5, 3, 4] ++ [5] ++ [9, 8, 6]
```

See? There is no duplication, just partitioning.

**Note:** Your program has a serious bug. Check this line

```
quicksort smallerOrEqual ++ [x] ++ larger
```

It basically works like this

```
(quicksort smallerOrEqual) ++ [x] ++ larger
```

So, the `larger` list is never sorted. You recursively have to sort both the smaller list and the greater list and finally merge them in to one. So, it should have been

```
(quicksort smallerOrEqual) ++ [x] ++ (quicksort larger)
```

which can be written without the brackets like this

```
quicksort smallerOrEqual ++ [x] ++ quicksort larger
```

Comment: You don't need those brackets: `quicksort smallerOrEqual ++ [x] ++ quicksort larger` works fine, because function application has higher precedence that the infix operator `++`.

Comment: @Jubobs Yup, we don't need them. But it might help him understand the mistake, right? Anyway, I included the bracket-less version also now :)

Comment: "List of numbers smaller than or equal to the pivot element" is a bit misleading, because it implies that it contains the pivot itself, which is then added again in point 2 hence leading to duplication. The crucial part is that this list is obtained as a filter over the tail `xs`, and not over the whole original list `x:xs`.

Comment: @chi You are right. I wanted to make exactly that point clearly. That is why I added those points. I edited them now. Please check if it is fine.

Comment: @thefourtheye Much better.